# How to JOIN postmeta table and get the posts before the date of custom field using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'd like to combine *wp_posts table* and *wp_postmeta table* and get the posts before the date of custom field.

**Code with only wp_posts table is below and it works fine**

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT DISTINCT
    MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
    YEAR( post_date ) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_date <= now( )
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'event'
    GROUP BY month , year
    ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC
    ");
```

I want to add "postmeta table" to "post table" and get only posts before the date of custom field
if it is "WP_Query", meta query would be below

```
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => date('Y/m/d'),
        'type' => 'DATE',
        'compare' => '>=',
    )
  )`
```

**I tried code below but it returns empty array.**

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT DISTINCT
    MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
    YEAR( post_date ) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
    ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_date <= now( )
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'event'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'end_date'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = date('Y/m/d')
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_type = 'DATE'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_compare = '>='
    GROUP BY month , year
    ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC
    ");
```

**When it is added only meta_key, it returns the same result as "Code for only wp_posts table"(first code)**

```
//same result as "Code for only wp_posts table"
$posts = $wpdb->get_results(
    "SELECT DISTINCT
    MONTH( post_date ) AS month,
    YEAR( post_date ) AS year
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
    ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
    WHERE post_status = 'publish'
    AND post_date <= now( )
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'event'
    AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'end_date'
    GROUP BY month , year
    ORDER BY year DESC, month ASC
    ");
```

I'd like to know how to add conditions
"key", "value" and "compare".

I'm very beginner on SQL and hope someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes I see between your original and new queries are the `LEFT JOIN` and the added conditions to your `WHERE` clause.  Adding a `LEFT JOIN` to your initial query won't result in an empty array unless one of these is true:

1) Your original query returned 0 rows
2) Your new query has additional filtering in the `WHERE` clause

If you want to return all your initial rows (i.e. from `$wpdb->posts`) and include any matching rows from `$wpdb->postmeta`, then just move the extra `AND` conditions from the `WHERE` clause to the `JOIN`:

```sql
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
ON $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
-- join conditions
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'end_date'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = date('Y/m/d')
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_type = 'DATE'
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_compare = '>='
-- filter conditions
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_date <= now( )
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'event'
```

Comment: This must be something basic. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.  Did that fix it for you?  Or are you still having issues?

Comment: Your code worked fine! The problem is I'm using ACF and this plugin save customfield original way and I need to do more reseach..
So this is another issue. Your explanation helped me a lot. Thank you again :)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped :)