# get_post_meta bringing back results, but $wpdb->postmeta doesn't

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to discover if post exists, based on `post_title` & metadata `post_language`.
Until now, the best way I discovered, was using methods appearing in posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421169/how-to-join-postmeta-table-and-get-the-posts-before-the-date-of-custom-field-usi), [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58593/check-if-post-title-exists-insert-post-if-doesnt-add-incremental-to-meta-if), or [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350624/prepare-wpdb-with-meta-key-and-meta-value).

Thing is this, that when I am calling directly `get_post_meta` method, I get the meta property value I was looking for

```
get_post_meta($post_exists_id, 'post_lang')[0] //returns "en" as expected
```

Furthermore, when I run my custom `post_exists` method, it will return me an ID.

```
function especialidades_post_exists( $title ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
        WHERE 1=1
        AND (p.post_title = %s)
        AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
    ";
    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( $query, $title ) 
    );
}
```

But if I will add a postmeta lookup into the method, it will fail, It will not find the postmeta property, and the query will return 0.

```
function especialidades_post_exists( $title, $language ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "
        SELECT p.ID
        FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
        WHERE 1=1
        AND (p.post_title = %s)
        AND (pm.post_lang = %s)
        AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
    ";
    return (int) $wpdb->get_var( 
        $wpdb->prepare( $query, $title, $language ) 
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing? The postmeta property is there (as I showed before by running `get_post_meta`), so how come it does not find it?

**Editing**

I applied this code, but still it does not returning me the desired result

```
$another_query_args = array(
   'name' => $item_name,
   'post_type' => 'especialidades',
   'meta_query'    => array (
      array (
         'key'     => 'post_lang',
         'value'   => $language,
         'compare' => '='
      )
   ),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $another_query_args );
```

The problem is that I got 3 languages: PT, ES & EN.
It's always returning me the first result (PT), even though I have 3 posts pf the 3 languages. I wish to check only if post of specific language exists.

If someone will be able to share me some light, on what's wrong in my method, I'll appreciate it a lot!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`AND (pm.post_lang = %s)` here you're assuming `post_lang` is a SQL table column, but it's not. The post meta table has columns like `post_id`, `meta_name`, and `meta_value`.

so `post_lang` is a `meta_name` and `$language` will be your `meta_value`

you're also missing `ON p.ID = pm.post_id` for your JOIN query.

so the final query should be like this:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM $wpdb->posts AS p
INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta AS pm
ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE 1=1
AND (p.post_title = %s)
AND (pm.meta_name = 'post_lang')
AND (pm.meta_value = %s)
AND (p.post_type = 'especialidades')
ORDER BY p.ID DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

Comment: Man its crazy, im running the code without the `language` part, and I am able to return a `unique id`, and the run `get_post_meta($post_exists_id, 'post_lang')[0]`, which return me the desired language. But searching for meta inside the `SELECT`, does not work!

Comment: Vijay Hardaha, maybe there is a problem with the whole function structure?

Comment: See in your SQL query you're using `AND` not `OR` so you're saying QUERY to find a post title and post meta together. when they both match then you'll get results. so make sure you understand your query and have the data that fulfills that QUERY Condition.

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I need: an AND statement. I need to get back a post with the title, and language and category. This is why it does not make sense that I don't receive back nothing in the `wpdb` statement, and I always get back the first result in the `WP_Query`